# removeClass addClass not responding

Tags: jquery

I was hoping to be able to use an icon-pack that I found online to customize a HTML5 video player but the png's render horribly. Like this:

HTML

```
<div id="play-pause" class="play"><img src='../assets/play.png'/></div>
```

JQuery

```
playButton.innerHTML = "<img src='../assets/pausebutton.png'/>";
```

If I want to use the icon-pack as typography (i.e. great rendering) I need to display them as div classes.
 
So I tried using removeClass and addClass like this:

HTML

```
<div id="play-pause" class="play play-icon"></div>
```

JQuery

```
playButton.removeClass( "play-icon" ).addClass('pause-icon');
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`playButton` looks like a DOM object reference(because you are setting `playButton.innerHTML` which works only if it is a dom object), the [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass)/[removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass) methods are properties of jQuery object so try

```
$(playButton).removeClass( "play-icon" ).addClass('pause-icon');
```

Comment: one symbol that makes all the difference :) Thank you Arun P Johny